# WPF cascading comboboxes with LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I do have a number of combo boxes on a custom control as below

```
<Label Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblCombobox1">
    Select value from Combobox1
</Label>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="12" Grid.Column="1" Name="cbxCombobox1"
        SelectionChanged="cbxCostCentre_SelectionChanged" />
<Label Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="0" Name="lblCombobox2">
    Select value from Combobox2</Label>
<ComboBox Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" Name="cbxCombobox2"/>
```

This custom control I’m using on a main window as below

```
<StackPanel Background="LightCyan">
<views:NewAccount HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    Margin="30" FontSize="14"/>
```

I’d need to do populate combo boxes cascading to have a previous combo box selected value as a filter parameter for the next one.
It seems as the following code could do it. It’s doing the filtering providing the Combobox2 with a list of values. However, I’m probably missing something as the LINQ query with “where” clause provides a result that is different if I ran it with T-SQL. It’s very similar but a few more or less values in the Combobox2 that is different from T-SQL list.

```
using System.Linq;
namespace AccountsSetup.UserControls
{
    public partial class NewAccount : UserControl 
    {
        public NewAccount() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (SQL.DBDataContext db = new SQL.DBDataContext())
            {
                var allCombobox1s = from t in db.Table1
                                     select t.Name;
                cbxCombobox1.ItemsSource = allCombobox1s;
            }
        }

        private void cbxCombobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {            
            using (SQL.DBDataContext dbs = new SQL.DBDataContext())
            {
                string value = "";
                if (cbxCombobox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
                    value = cbxCombobox1.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
                var allCombobox2s = (from t in dbs.View1
                                       where t.Combobox1.Contains(value)
                                       select t.Name).Distinct(); 
                cbxCombobox2.ItemsSource = allCombobox2s;

            }
```

I did try to change the Combobox2 into the following code. But, it’s the same result.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="13" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="cbxCombobox2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=cbxCombobox1,
    Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Please, advise what corrections could be done in the code.

Thanks

Comment: What's the TSQL and the `View1` table looks like? What exactly is the difference?

Comment: `cbxCombobox1.ItemsSource = allCombobox1s` should read `cbxCombobox1.ItemsSource = allCombobox1s.ToList()`.  Similarly `cbxCombobox2.ItemsSource = allCombobox2s;` should be `cbxCombobox2.ItemsSource = allCombobox2s.ToList();`

Comment: Thank you for the correction suggestion to add .ToList(). I did it.

While all fields exist in View1 the reason I'm using Table1 is a one field that is also in View1 is a primary one in Table1. I could also get it from View1 with Distinct however.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's not redundant as the LINQ query is ended with .ToList() also.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the value of the SelectedItem property of the first ComboBox with the value of the Name column in the view.

Try this:

```
private void cbxCombobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    using (SQL.DBDataContext dbs = new SQL.DBDataContext())
    {
        string value = cbxCombobox1.SelectedItem as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            var allCombobox2s = (from t in dbs.View1
                                 where t.Name != null && t.Name.Contains(value)
                                 select t.Name).Distinct().ToList();
            cbxCombobox2.ItemsSource = allCombobox2s;
        }
    }
}
```